# Omniauth Service Unavailable Error for Twitter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter, omniauth

I am using omniauth and twitter login for my site. However, whenever I try to login, it gave this error:

```
Started GET "/auth/failure?message=service_unavailable" for 98.83.218.118 at 2011-11-12 11:27:58 -0500
  Processing by SessionsController#failure as HTML
  Parameters: {"message"=>"service_unavailable"}
```

The only clue I have is that it might be an [SSL error](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/pull/429).

However, I have no idea on how to debug the cause of the error.

Here is my current configuration for twitter:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :twitter, 'REDACTED', 'REDACTED'
end
```

Comment: What version of omniauth are you using?  There have been some major changes recently in v1.0 and this information would be helpful.

Comment: I am using omniauth 1.0 in my Gemfile.lock.

Comment: You will also need the omniauth-twitter gem then.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like ssl issue in my project.

For development mode you can off ssl. Then you can work without this issue.

add this in develoment.rb:

```
OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
```

And about how fix SSL certificates:
[Twitter API SSL Root CA Certificate](http://dev.twitter.com/discussions/533)

Comment: I download and upload cacert.pem as well ca-bundle.crt.txt. It now gave me the error of OAuth::Unauthorized (401 Unauthorized).

Answer (score 1):

I don't really like the solution suggested in at twitter dev support (as linked by Yahor Zhuchkou), which suggest downloading just a bunch of certificates from an unsecure server.

And while turning of verify peer will work in production that isn't really a solution. What you need to do is to point omniauth to the correct PEM file, which should contain something like, the Verisign Root Certificate which backs Twitter's own certificate (i:/C=US/O=VeriSign, Inc./OU=Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G2/OU=(c) 1998 VeriSign, Inc. - For authorized use only/OU=VeriSign Trust Network):

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

(If you're using Ubuntu you may find it here: `/etc/ssl/certs/Verisign_Class_3_Public_Primary_Certification_Authority_-_G2.pem` )

Don't know why omniauth or ruby openssl implementation isn't finding this, but you can explicitly link to this pem file with the following option:

```
provider :twitter, 'REDACTED', 'REDACTED', {
  :client_options => {:ca_file => '/etc/ssl/certs/Verisign_Class_3_Public_Primary_Certification_Authority_-_G2.pem'}
}
```